# SQLAlchemy models attribute operations and DB access

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, getattr

Let's say that I have SQLAlchemy ORM model instance `model` and name of it's attribute `attr_name`.

Is there a way to determine whether `getattr(model, attr_name)` will or won't query the database? I mean that I need a function `getattr_does_emit_sql(model, attr_name)` returning `True` or `False`.

Comment: Hmm. Are you asking if it can be determined programmatically, at runtime, or manually (by debugging and inspecting models objects, logging, etc..)?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity - question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The function is

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import QueryableAttribute
def getattr_does_emit_sql(model, attr_name):
    return (attr_name not in model.__dict__ 
        and hasattr(type(model), attr_name
        and isinstance(getattr(type(model), attr_name), QueryableAttribute)
    )
```